# Print WPF Page to a PCL File in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, printer-control-language

I would like to print a WPF page to a PCL file (so that it can be faxed). Is there a reasonable way to do this in the code or should I just print out to a PCL printer driver? (I am inclined towards the print driver, but if there is a cleaner solution I'd rather go with a better option.)

P.s. [WPF Printing to fit page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931961/wpf-printing-to-fit-page) is a great example of WPF printing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a thought.
You could print the WPF window to a BMP first and then convert to a PCL. That's how I would do it at least.

Here is some information of converting the WPF window to a BMP.
[Generating a screenshot of a WPF window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5124825/generating-a-screenshot-of-a-wpf-window)

Here is some information on converting from a BMP to a PCL
http://haykmanucharyan.net/Default.aspx?mode=2&id=33

Comment: I agree with Alex, this is the simplest approach.  You could do lots of work in outputting PCL file with fonts and text etc but his option is by far the shortest distance between A and B.