# Scale Canvas to fit Page while printing

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I want to print the Image which I draw in Canvas. The Image height and width are dynamic and often very big in size. I would like to fit the image which I draw to fit paper size(Size may vary as user can select A4, A6 etc.).

I find this  [WPF Printing to fit page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7931961/wpf-printing-to-fit-page)  The code is doing Layout Transform but I think I need RenderTransform(Correct me, If I am wrong). How can I do this ?

Comment: Have you tried it with LayoutTransform? Does it not work? What's the issue exactly?

Comment: @doubleYou Render transform worked. Thank you