# PrintDialog.PrintVisual for non-active VisualElements?

Tags: wpf, printing, printdialog

### Introduction

I have an application with a MainWindow (MVVM) consisting of a `TabViewer` with 5 Tabs. Each Tab contains a `ScrollViewer`, a `Grid` and several `UserControls` (MVC) within the `Grid`.

Xaml of my MainWindow:

```
<Window x:Class="CharacterSheetGenerator.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:CharacterSheetGenerator.Control"
    xmlns:help="clr-namespace:CharacterSheetGenerator.Helpers"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="1600" Width="1320" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
<Grid Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <Button Name="SaveButton" Command="{Binding LoadCommand}" Width="40" Height="30">
            <Image Source="/images/LoadButtonPicture.png"/>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="LoadButton" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Width="40" Height="30">
            <Image Source="/images/SaveButtonpicture.png" />
        </Button>
        <!-- Print Button currently in xaml.cs of my MainWindow -->
        <Button Name="Print Button" Click="Button3_Click" Width="40" Height="30">
            <Image Source="/images/PrintButtonPicture.png"/>
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <TabControl Grid.Row="1">
        <TabItem Width="75" Height="20" Header="Übersicht">
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" >
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <help:BubbleScrollEvent />
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <!-- Grid I'd like to print -->
                <Grid Name="Übersicht">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="180"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1">
                    <StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="34" FontWeight="Bold" Text="Heldendokument"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="20" Text="Persönliche Daten" TextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                        <ctrl:CharacterAttributes VerticalAlignment="Top" AttributeList="{Binding Attributes, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </StackPanel>

                            <Grid Grid.Row="2">
                                <StackPanel>
                                <ctrl:CharacterOverview VerticalAlignment="Top" CharacterInformation="{Binding CharacterInformation}" StatusValues="{Binding StatusValues, Mode=TwoWay}" Traits="{Binding Traits, Mode=TwoWay}" Expirience="{Binding Expirience}" TraitClickCommand="{Binding OpenTraitViewCommand}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>

            </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Width="75" Height="20" Header="Fertigkeiten">
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <help:BubbleScrollEvent />
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <!-- Second Grid I'd like to print -->
                <Grid Name="Fertigkeiten">
                    <!-- [...] -->
        </TabItem>
        <!-- [...] -->
```

Example of a my first Tab:

[image: First Tab "Übersicht" example view]

I've marked each of my UserControls with a few red borders.

### Problem

The cyan dottet line represents the area, that would be printet on a DinA4 page, if I simply use `PrintDialog.PrintVisual(Übersicht, "Printing Übersicht")` I've implemented the [code from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8990485/7696590) and modified it in order to print all and not just one Tabs, but I've encountered a few problems.

Modified Code:

```
   //I tried to create an array and iterate through it
     System.Windows.FrameworkElement[] elements = { Übersicht as System.Windows.FrameworkElement, Fertigkeiten as System.Windows.FrameworkElement, Kampf as System.Windows.FrameworkElement,
                                                       Zauber as System.Windows.FrameworkElement, Inventar as System.Windows.FrameworkElement,};

        PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
        if (printDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {

            foreach (FrameworkElement e in elements)
            {

                //store original scale
                Transform originalScale = e.LayoutTransform;
                //get selected printer capabilities
                System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities = printDialog.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDialog.PrintTicket);


                //get scale of the print wrt to screen of WPF visual
                double scale = Math.Min(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth / 1281, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight /
                               1800); // I had to change ActualWidth and Height to static Values, as Grids in Tabs, which haven't been opened at least once since the start of the application had no actual size

                //Transform the Visual to scale
                e.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);

                //get the size of the printer page
                System.Windows.Size sz = new System.Windows.Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);

                //update the layout of the visual to the printer page size.
                e.Measure(sz);
                e.Arrange(new System.Windows.Rect(new System.Windows.Point(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), sz));

                //now print the visual to printer to fit on the one page.
                printDialog.PrintVisual(e, "My Print");

                //apply the original transform.
                e.LayoutTransform = originalScale;

            }

        }
```

Now there are a few issues with this:

- All `UserControls` which haven't been loaded since the lauch of the application will be emtpy (My second Page has a DataGrid. The rows are still there, but all the values are missing)
- If a Tab has been opened, but isn't the current open one, the UserControls have their data, but aren't resized accordingly (same problem with the cyan dottet lines)

**let me show you a Example of my second Tab:** (these are scanned DinA4 Pages)

First issue: (you can see the UserControl with the colored Boxes still works, because it has already been loaded on the first page)

[image]

Second Issue:

[image]

**Still missing some code? Go to my [GitHub](https://github.com/Azzarrel/CharacterSheetGenerator) and clone the project to try it for yourself.**

**Questions:**

- **What causes this arguably weird behavior, how can I solve it?**
- **Is there another way but printDialog.PrintVisual() to print my Pages?**

Comment: How do the problem usercontrols get their layout usually? Templated from data or what? Will their viewmodels perhaps not be there with that data when you do this process?

Comment: My UserContrls use the MVC pattern. I didn't specify their DataContext, but instead set the DataContext of their Children to their `DependencyProperties` like `<DataGrid x:Name="grid1" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=Skills, Mode=TwoWay}" `, which seems to be the common practice to handle UserControls with DependencyProperties

Comment: Datacontext is itself a dependency property which is marked so it inherits down the visual tree. Hence if you set the datacontext of a window, a usercontrol in that has the same datacontext. As would a datagrid in the usercontrol. Rows in a datagrid have the datacontext of whatever item they correspond to in the itemssource. Columns are an abstraction.